# How do I get my PIXMA MP250 printer to work on 14.10

Tags: drivers, printing, 14.10, canon

I have tried installing the software, with no success.  When I go to printers under system settings, the button to add a printer is greyed out even though the printer is plugged up.  I tried running this command to get the driver:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mp250series
E: Invalid operation
```

then tried one similar

```
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mp240series
E: unable to locate package cnijfilter-mp240series
```

Tried downloading package directly from canon website for linux 64 bit, but not sure how to execute it.

Comment: Possibly related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/798265/canon-printer-drivers-for-ubuntu-15-10 . Try going through the same steps you just listed, but replacing `ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk` with `ppa:michael-gruz/canon`

Answer (score 1):

If you have downloaded the `cnijfilter...gz` package from Canon's website, you should have what you need to get your printer working.

Assuming that you downloaded it to the Downloads folder, execute these steps:

1. Open the Downloads folder in a file manager
2. Find the `cnijfilter...gz` package and extract it into the Downloads folder.  Depending on how your system is set up, this may be as simple as right-clicking it and selecting "Extract now" or similar.
3. Open a terminal window.  Go to the Downloads folder by typing `cd Downloads`.  List the contents of the folder by typing `ls`.  Then cd to the `cnij.....deb` folder that you created by extracting the files.
4. List the contents of the new folder by typing `ls`.  If everything has worked so far, you will see two directories and a script called `install.sh`.
5. Execute the install script by typing `sudo ./install.sh`.  You will be prompted for a password.  Enter your login password.  Nothing will be displayed as you type.
6. Answer the questions in the install script.

If this process completes properly, you should now be able to print.