# Canon printer drivers for Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10

I have a canon Pixma MP210 which has never worked on Ubuntu.

I have researched on Ubuntu forums and the advise was `sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mp210 series` but this doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mp210 series
```

can't be correct. It would install two packages, one named "series".

---

To install Canon printer driver support for ubuntu you need to add a personal archive. You do that with ...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon
sudo apt-get update
```

Disconnect your Canon printer from your computer or turn it off. Then, install the driver. For mp210 this would be:

```
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mp210series
```

This also works for lots of other canon printers.

The PPA contains drivers for ip100, iP1800, iP1880, iP1890, ip1000, ip1500, ip1900, ip2200, ip2500, ip2]00, ip3300, ip3500, ip4200, ip4500, ip4700, ip4800, ip5200, ip6600, i7500, mg5200, mg5500, mg6100, mg8100, mp140, mp160, mp190, mp210,mp240, mp500, mp510, mp520, mp540, mp550, mp560, mp600, mp630, mp640, mx320, mx330, mx350, mx360, mx410, mx420, mx860, mx870, mx880, Pixus 550, 560, 580, 860, 865, 950, 990, ip4100, ip8600. (in case someone else is looking for a Canon driver).

Comment: after the text ppa: the name" michael-gruz" is part of the text or ones name?

Comment: This is the message which occurs when the above is entered " Unable to locate package cnijfilter-mp210series"